# Angular refresh component

Tags: angular

i have location drop down in top nav bar. on change location, i have to load entire application based on that location data, so i need to get all components data to be refreshed, that is why i am approaching this step.

> core.js:5847 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match
>   any routes. URL Segment: 'RefreshComponent' Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'RefreshComponent'

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
) { }
```

i have used javascript `setTimeout(() => { location.reload(); });` it worked fine, i dont want to reload the page, just want to refresh the component i tried below code. but when i use console error is coming.

```
changeLocation(locationData) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
    }); 
}
```

Am i missing any configuration .?

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: do you have a route definition for the path `RefreshComponent`?

Comment: No @ChrisY, Do i need to add that .?

Comment: @Developer Yes.

Comment: So i need to generate component for that right .?

Comment: No. You don't need to unless you want to do some processing while refreshing.  I have posted the answer.

Comment: Yes. As far as I see what you are trying to do is kind of a "hack" to be able to reload the whole component because you'r probably doing some data fetching in the `ngOnInit` there.  
Best practice though would be to just trigger a new fetching of current data and subscribe to them via Observables. Then you should not have to reload the component.

Comment: @ChrisY I am agreeing with your approach, only refresh the data which needs to be refreshed, but as the component reloading goes as per OP question, unless you are doing some fancy stuff, you don't need `/ReloadComponent` as overhead.

Comment: @ChrisY, i have location drop down in top nav bar. on change location, i have to load  entire application based on that location data, so i need to get all components data to be refreshed, that is why i am approaching this step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probally dont have `RefreshComponent` route in you route configuration.

As far as refresing your component goes, just modify your function as follows, you don't need `RefreshComponent` route.

Replace `navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent',...` with `navigateByUrl('/',...`

```js
changeLocation(locationData) {

    // save current route first
    const currentRoute = this.router.url;

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
        this.router.navigate([currentRoute]); // navigate to same route
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Now its redirecting to home page instead of refreshing

Comment: whats the route for component, which you need to refresh?

Comment: See, `this.router.url` i used current component. user can change location in top nav bar. its not specific to single component.

Comment: This is a great solution ! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link you are looking for.

https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/refresh-angular-component-without-navigation-148a87c2de3f

As per the link.

```
mySubscription: any;
```

Add following in the constructor of your component.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
    return false;
};

this.mySubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  // Trick the Router into believing it's last link wasn't previously loaded
  this.router.navigated = false;
  }
});
```

And make sure to unsubscribe to "mySubscription" like below

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 if (this.mySubscription) {
   this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```